# apply a function to divide an array by a vector

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have to apply a function which devide a value by another to every row of an numpy array.

here the function:

```
def myfunc(a, b):
   return (a/b)
```

my numpy ndarray look like this and it represent the "a" value:

```
[[ 1  2  3  4 ]
 [ 5  6  7  8 ]]
```

and my list which is my b value, looks like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The result I want is :

```
[[1 1 1 1]
 [5 3 2.33 2]]
```

To do that, I can't use a loop, so I tried with np.vectorize. Here my code:

```
test = np.vectorize(myfunc)
test(a, b)
```

this return :

```
array([[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[
[1]
<NDArray 1 @cpu(0)>,

[1]
<NDArray 1 @cpu(0)>,

[1]
<NDArray 1 @cpu(0)>,

[1]
<NDArray 1 @cpu(0)>]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]],
...
```

so every cell is devide4 times by the first value of b.

but for an unknown reason my code do not work for the ndarray. when I tried with an normal array, it's working. Example:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5,6,7,8]])
b = [1,2,3,4]
def my(coord, shape):
   return (coord/shape)
myfunc = np.vectorize(my)
myfunc(a, b)
```

result:

```
array([[1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ],
       [5.        , 3.        , 2.33333333, 2.        ]])
```

Do you guys know what I can do ? I really don't know how I get the ndarray, and why I can't have the right result.

Comment: `np.vectorize` applies (in default mode) scalar values to your function.  It does not 'do things by row' or other groupings.  And don't be tempted to use it as a performance tool - it isn't that (see it's disclaimer note).

Comment: In numpy everything is an array (`ndarray` class).  Where they differ is in the shape and number of dimensions.  Your description will be clearer if you talk of dimensions, not 'vector' or 'normal array'.  And of course Python has lists.

Comment: I probably misunderstand you and it's to good to be true, but why don't you just use: `np.divide(a,b)`?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need `np.vectorize`?

```
In [511]: a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5,6,7,8]]) 
     ...: b = [1,2,3,4]                                                                                      

In [512]: b = np.array(b)                                                                                    
In [513]: a.shape                                                                                            
Out[513]: (2, 4)
In [514]: b.shape                                                                                            
Out[514]: (4,)
In [515]: a / b                                                                                              
Out[515]: 
array([[1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ],
       [5.        , 3.        , 2.33333333, 2.        ]])
```

Comment: If you use `np.divide`, you don't even have to do the conversion.